# Не грузятся картинки в flask сайте когда запускаю на localhost

Tags: python, flask

Есть обычный код flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Он отправляет на html страницу с картинками прописанные в таком виде:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/whatsapp.svg') }}" alt="whatsapp">
или
<img class="candle" src="../static/images/candle.png">
```

Но почему именно на локальном сервере после перезагрузки картинки абсолютно рандомно грузятся (что-то грузистя, а что-то нет). Если страницу перезагрузить холодной перезагрузкой один раз всё работает, а последующий раз начинает тупить. Как это исправить?([image: flask]

На heroku всё работает нормально

Comment: В папке `static/images` присутствуют те файлы?

Comment: Да, все файлы есть